# how to add individual elements in an array

Tags: iphone

i am trying to add individual integers to a certain array
my array is in this form
`array= number +1`
how can i make lets say number be a `array = 2 +3 +1`
where 2 and 3 are two different distinct obhects that should be commutatively added.
i hope i am clear. I dont want the numbers to be added so that the aboce equations would equal 0. i want it to be equal to 2 then 3 then 1....

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray????

Do something like this:

```
int d = 0;
for (d = 0; i <100; i++)
 {
 [array addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", d]];
 }
```

or whatever you want it to be

edit:

To add the numbers, just use `intvalue`

Comment: no, i have an array that contains numbers that correspond to questions in a text file that get displayed. i want to be able to make lets say a fixed way of displayed these views in an order. if i do array = 1 it will show me the 2nd question so i want to do smthing like array = 1+3 to be able to see the 2nd and 4th questions

Comment: sry for the questions but how would i use intvalue?

Comment: `[[array objectAtIndex:index] intValue];`